# Trouble trying to zoom to graphic (ArcGIS 9.3.1, VBA)

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, vba

I am writing an application where one of the things it does is create a point then creates buffer (which is a graphic) at the specific point, what I want to do is when the buffer has been created, is to zoom to the extent of the buffer.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work

```
Dim penv2 As IEnvelope
Set penv2 = New Envelope
Set penv2 = pActiveView.extent
Dim pArea As IArea
Set pArea = pElement.Geometry.Envelope
penv2.CenterAt pArea.Centroid            
pActiveView.Refresh
```

I've also tried

```
Dim penv2 As IEnvelope
Set penv2 = pElement.Geometry.Envelope
pActiveView.Extent = penv2 
pActiveView.Refresh
```

But nothing happens. Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ZoomToElement()
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument

    Dim pGCS As IGraphicsContainerSelect
    Set pGCS = pMxDoc.FocusMap

    If pGCS.ElementSelectionCount <> 1 Then
        Debug.Print "select just one element first"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim pEnv As IEnvelope
    Set pEnv = pGCS.SelectedElement(0).Geometry.Envelope

    Dim pAV As IActiveView
    Set pAV = pMxDoc.FocusMap

    pAV.Extent = pEnv
    pAV.Refresh
End Sub
```